# Intellij|Maven Repository not found JFoenix

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to add the `Jfoenix` library to my project via `Maven` but i'm getting an error in my `pom.xml` of `Dependency com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.8 Not Found`

This is what I have:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jfoenix-repo</id>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The url I use is provided in that particular dependency's page. Which one should I be using?

Comment: mvnrepository is not a consumable repository. The given dependency is available in central repository so no supplemental repository configuration is needed.

Comment: removed it and I had to restart my IDE. Plugins are currently downloading. Thanks